# How to get attribute data based on the GeoJSON you clicked Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I'm trying to pull the attribute data from a GeoJSON layer.

```
var neighLyr = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("data/neighbourhood.geojson",{
    }).addTo(mymap);


neighLyr.on('click', function (e) {
    console.log(e.layer.properties.id); 
    });
```

Why doesn't this code work ? It keeps saying the id is undefined. 
I'm using https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js

Comment: Your code does not work because e.layer is Leaflet layer object (feature group) which knows nothing about GeoJSON feature properties. If you want to get info about individual GeoJSON features, you have to use `onEachFeature` option of `L.GeoJSON.AJAX` object.

Comment: Or go with the event's `sourceTarget` as per https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#event-sourcetarget

Comment: Nice thanks. I got it to work with the code below.

Answer (score 2):

I found out the answer to my question, thanks guys. 
Below is the code that works.

```
    var neigh
    var neighLyr = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("data/neighbourhood.geojson",{
        style: myStyle,
        onEachFeature : function (feature, layer){
            layer.on('mouseover' , function(e) {
                neigh = feature.properties.pri_neigh;
            });
        }
    }).addTo(mymap);
```